# How to show Checked Checkboxes with stored data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4.2

i have this data in database (table permit_upgrade_qualifi) :

1. id = 1 , title = طراحی
2. id = 2 , title = نظارت
3. id = 3 , title = اجرا

That this data, load with Foreach in view :

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="checkbox-list">
    @foreach($permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi as $ppuq)
        <label class="checkbox-inline" for="ppuq-label-{{$ppuq->id}}">
            <input type="checkbox" name="ppuq[]" id="ppuq-label-{{$ppuq->id}}" value="{{$ppuq->id}}" {{ $permit_upgrade_qualifi->permit_id = $permit->id  ? 'checked' : '' }}>{{$ppuq->title}}
        </label>
    @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

and my code in Controller :

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $idd = Sentry::getUser()->id;
        try {

            $permit = UpgradePermit::findOrFail($id);

            $base = Base::all();
            $permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi = PermitUpgradeQualifi::all();
            $permit_upgrade_qualifi = DB::table('permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi')->where('permit_id', $id)->get();

           // return $permit_upgrade_qualifi;

            $cites = DB::table('provinces')->get();
            $profile = User::find($idd);

            return View::make('manager.user_up_permit.edit', compact('permit','base','permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi','permit_upgrade_qualifi', 'cites', 'profile'));

        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return Redirect::route('dashboard.user.up-permit.index')->with('danger', 'درخواست معتبر نمیباشد.');
        }
    }
```

and this data in database, is stored checkbox  (table permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi) :

1. permit_id = 300   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 1
2. permit_id = 302   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 1
3. permit_id = 300   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 2
4. permit_id = 302   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 2
5. permit_id = 303   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 2
6. permit_id = 303   |  permit_upgrade_qualifi_id = 3

now, how can i show checked checkboxes in view ?

Thanks

Comment: you can create model for the table permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi and use `Model::all()` to fetch all data

Comment: in Controller code, create with variable $permit_upgrade_qualifi for fech data, this worked on controller when return variable, but not worked in view and get error "ErrorException: Attempt to assign property of non-object".

Comment: `$permit_upgrade_qualifi->permit_id = $permit->id` isn't this making an assignment instead of making a comparison? you should use at least use `==` equality or better identity

Comment: Yes, that's right, but this is not the main problem.

Comment: Use Eloquents `pluck()` method, to get an array of permit_upgrade_qualifi_id for that permit. Pass it to the view, then you can do something like `{{ in_array( $permit->id, $array_of_ids_for_each_permit)  ? 'checked' : '' }}`

Comment: test it, but checked all checkboxes, not checked checkboxes based on table permit_permit_upgrade_qualifi.

Comment: No one is accountable ?